404 not found postman
i run my spring application and it's showing no errors, here's my controller
package com.testAOP.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.testAOP.model.Employee;
import com.testAOP.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;
@GetMapping("/add/employee")
public Employee addEmployee(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("empId") String empId) {
return employeeService.createEmployee(name, empId);
}
}

and my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TPSpring5</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TPSpring5</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

so my app is running on port 8080 , but when i enter http://localhost:8080/add/employee?name=test&empId=1 (GET) on postman , i get 404 not found
{
    "timestamp": "2024-05-10T21:59:18.175+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/add/employee"
}

i tried checking annotations but i dont see anything wrong, and my console shows that my app is running
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.5)

2024-05-10T22:57:51.735+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] .example.demo.TpSpring5Application    : Starting TpSpring5Application using Java 17.0.10 with PID 21860 (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\studies 2A\S4\java api\tp1\TPSpring5\target\classes started by DELL in C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\studies 2A\S4\java api\tp1\TPSpring5)
2024-05-10T22:57:51.737+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] .example.demo.TpSpring5Application    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-05-10T22:57:52.357+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-05-10T22:57:52.390+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 25 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-05-10T22:57:52.900+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-05-10T22:57:52.925+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service cat]
2024-05-10T22:57:52.925+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.20]
2024-05-10T22:57:52.995+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.cat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-05-10T22:57:52.995+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1202 ms
2024-05-10T22:57:53.114+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] .zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-05-10T22:57:53.325+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] .zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:39fc9a6a-c78c-45d5-853b-97c116ba1079 user=SA
2024-05-10T22:57:53.327+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] .zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-05-10T22:57:53.372+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo e: default]
2024-05-10T22:57:53.418+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.4.Final
2024-05-10T22:57:53.454+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-05-10T22:57:53.677+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-05-10T22:57:54.010+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-05-10T22:57:54.016+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-05-10T22:57:54.075+01:00  WARN 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-05-10T22:57:54.469+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-05-10T22:57:54.482+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [           main] .example.demo.TpSpring5Application    : Started TpSpring5Application in 3.112 seconds (process running for 3.723)
2024-05-10T22:59:10.174+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.cat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-05-10T22:59:10.174+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-05-10T22:59:10.183+01:00  INFO 21860 --- [TPSpring5] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms


Welcome to Stack Overflow. FYI, I fixed your syntax hightlighting and removed the ANSI colour codes from your log to make it more readable. Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Thank you.

I assume that your main class is located in com.testAOP.main; but your controller class is in com.testAOP.controller;.
With that package structure Spring cannot see your controller because it NOT placed in exact package com.testAOP.main; in order to fix that you need to move all your classes into subpackage of your main method class location.
My wild guess would be to move controller from com.testAOP.controller; to com.testAOP.main; or com.testAOP.main.controller; and restart your spring boot application.
As long your components like controller are in subpackage of main method package location, you should be good to go.

That might be true, because in the log I see the frasgment .example.demo.TpSpring5Application, i.e. probably the application is in com.example.demo, not in com-testAOP. Hence, component scan probably fails.

Thanks, i didnt notice that my main class is in the wrong placement

I would appreciate if you would accept my answer as correct
